# How to adjust bitmap image contrast in android?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, bitmapimage, contrast

I went through lot more techniques.But nothing could solve my query.None of those techniques are proper.Either the image becomes blur or become completely dark.So, i need a specific algorithm to adjust the bitmap image contrast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

http://android.okhelp.cz/bitmap-set-contrast-and-brightness-android/

hope help someone